# Elastic Beanstalk not deploying and cannot find error in error logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am having an issue getting my application to deploy on the elastic beanstalk. It works on my local machine flawlessly however when I try to deploy to beanstalk it fails and rolls back to the sample application. Then when I check the error.log file it is empty. Also when I check the node.js file the only output is

```
> Elastic-Beanstalk-Sample-App@0.0.1 start /var/app/current
> node app.js

Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/
```

I don't understand how to find the error it sends when deploying to the server. Where should I be looking?

Comment: share the output of these two logs:
/var/log/eb-activity.log
/var/log/eb-commandprocessor.log

Comment: I mean only parts where you see errors, there will be truckloads of stuff in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it was deleting my logs is I had rolling with additional batch enabled. Thereby deleting my logs on rollback. As far as the error was concerned it was an error in my code that caused it to require a module that didn't exist

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are running the app with the HOST set to localhost (127.0.0.1). The localhost is accessible only to internal processes on your Beanstalk instance. Change the host to `0.0.0.0` so that the app can be accessed from other IP addresses.